# Fgets() only able to read one line (last line)

Tags: c

Hey guys I'm having a problem with `fgets()`. It is only reading the last line of my program. So I am getting incorrect data with the `fgets`. I am trying to store a substring from that file. (Makes sense? :/)

I know it only reads the last line as I have done various tests, seeing if it could find a substring and it can only find it if it's on the last line.

CODE:

```
//Input
  FILE *ptr_file;


  //fclose(ptr_file);
    ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
  char *fgets(file, ptr_file);
  if (!ptr_file)
     return 1;
{
      while (fgets(file,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)   
     printf("%s\n",file);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you wanted the `{` after `while (fgets(file,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)` rather than before.

Comment: @Lori that should not make any difference as shown, but perhaps whole code would.

Comment: What is ` char *fgets(file, ptr_file);` supposed to do, and why does it compile?

Comment: Function declaration wrong and in middle of code: `char *fgets(file, ptr_file);`

Comment: "... only reading the last line of my program."  --> did you mean "... only reading the last line of `input.txt`."  ?  Post is unclear.  Where is `file` defined?

Comment: prototype for `fgets` should be in `stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a string of size 1000 to store the input.

```
    char file[1000];
```

Just before or after the FILE declaration.